# I/O error while reading BCP format file

Tags: sql-server-2008-r2, bcp

Today I created a new staging table and a BCP .fmt file.  I created some test data and attempted to run the BCP utility from the command line:

[image: BCP Error]

I've got about 20 different format files and staging tables from previous work and this is the first time I have encountered this error.

How can I fix this error?

Please note, I have added my solution below, but if you have other answers, please add them in.  The answer was so quirky/obscure that I think it may help others.

Answer (score 32, accepted):

Basically, this one was really strange.  In order for it to work, make sure there is an empty line after the last column defined in the format file.  I added an extra empty line, resaved the file, and then the BCP utility ran the file successfully.  I've indicated the extra line with a red rectangle.

[image: BCP Fix]

Comment: Oh wow. Thanks for that. You've probably just saved me hours.

Comment: I have a problem but the opposite way. I'm exporting an XML field into a file, and the resulting file has an extra empty line at the end.

Comment: @luiggig - You could run a post process to remove the extra whitespace at the end.  Not sure if there is a BCP option to remove.

Comment: This seems to be an undocumented requirement of the format file. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms191479.aspx "PWAusDevMGAM" already mentioned in the user-comments, and I've also notified the documentation-team.