# Additional bytes being prepended to file when saved to SQL Server

Tags: c#, sql-server, wcf, stream, bcp

I receive a file through a SFTP session in a WCF service. This file is being read into a `MemoryStream` object. I've output this stream successfully to a file on disk & verified that the file is transferred successfully (this was done using a `FileStream` instead of the `MemoryStream`).

But when I convert this `MemoryStream` to a `byte[]` to save it to a SQL Server table (with the column declared as `VARBINARY(MAX)`), it seems that 8 bytes are being prepended to the file.

As an example, I've uploaded a .txt file using the WCF SFTP Service & saved it to the database. Then, using BCP, I've output the file to disk. Upon opening the file, the first line has "U       " prepended to it (a "U" and 7 spaces).

The same happens to Office documents. I've done the same procedure as mentioned above for a .xls file, which at the start is 49Kb big. But upon outputting it using BCP, the file is corrupt & is 50Kb big.

Oddly, .pdf files seem to save & export correctly.

A few snippets of the code I'm using:

**To convert the stream to a byte array**

```
var stream = (MemoryStream)data;
stream.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);
byte[] m_Bytes = stream.ToArray();
```

**To save the byte array to SQL Server**

```
cmd.Parameters.Add("@File", System.Data.SqlDbType.VarBinary, -1).Value = file;
```

**To export the file from SQL Server to a file using BCP**

```
bcp "SELECT [File] FROM SFTPUpload.dbo.Upload" queryout "C:\SFTP\Test.txt" -T -N -S Server_Name\Instance_Name
```

Could this be a problem with the method I'm using to save the file to the database, or how I'm retrieving the file using BCP? The latter seems more probable, since saving the file directly to disk does not corrupt it.

Any help or advice would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

BCP writes out data in its BCP format. The BCP format must contain more than just the binary data because it supports multiple columns and rows. Export the binary data using a method that preserves its bytes exactly.

My guess is that the initial 8 bytes are the blob length.

Comment: You are right about the 8-byte length prefix (overloaded as a NULL indicator) for varbinary(MAX) data types.

Comment: Perfect, thank you for the swift reply. I'm busy putting together an exporter app to pull the files from the DB. And I've learnt a few things about BCP now in the process...

Comment: Just to confirm for the sake of completeness, after writing the exporter app to export the bytes as-is, the files were no longer being corrupted.

Answer (score 5):

I just had the same issue, and here's how to fix it.

In my example, I had a SQL Server table called "`External_File`" and one of its fields, `ExtFile_Data`, was a `varbinary(max)` containing raw file data, usually of an entire Excel file.

[image: External_File]

What I wanted to do was use `bcp` to quickly export this raw data into a file on our database server.

This command *almost* worked perfectly...

```
--  This does not work - don't use it !!
EXEC master..xp_cmdshell 'BCP "select ef.ExtFile_Data 
   FROM [External_File] ef  WHERE ExtFile_ID = 1005" 
   queryout "G:\ImportData\TestFile.xlsm" -T -N'
```

...but it added 8 bytes at the start of each file, so none of them could be opened.

The solution was to make bcp use a formatting file, which I called "BCPformat.fmt"...

```
EXEC master..xp_cmdshell 'BCP "select ef.ExtFile_Data 
   FROM [External_File] ef  WHERE ExtFile_ID = 1005" 
   queryout "G:\ImportData\TestFile.xlsm" -T 
   -f "G:\ImportData\BCPformat.fmt" '
```

Here's what my `BCPformat.fmt` file looked like.

```
10.0
1
1 SQLBINARY 0 0 "" 1 ExtFile_Data ""
```

Note that your formatting file *must match* the structure of data you're attempting to export.

In my case, I was exporting just one column, called `ExtFile_Data`, so this is the field name in my .fmt file.  Your field names *will* be different, so your .fmt file will need to reflect this.

But. with this .fmt file in place (and accessible by whichever SQL Server user is running the script), I could successfully export raw data into an Excel file, without those extra 8 bytes at the start.

And this method is *hugely faster* at turning large chunks of raw SQL Server data into a real file than any other method I could find.

It's just ironic that `bcp` doesn't have a simple flag to dump a `varbinary(max)` field into a file *without* adding anything onto this chunk of data.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Yes it does help a lot Mike. More info about file format can be found https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/import-export/non-xml-format-files-sql-server

FYI, there is also an XML version for format files, but XML validation by BCP would not allow Prefix Length of 0 :(

Comment: FYI if you are getting a strange `I/O error while reading BCP format file` check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9948130/i-o-error-while-reading-bcp-format-file)